# Simple login activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication

Can somebody tell me what I doing wrong?
I want to make a simple login activity. Insert password, for example "112", activate by ENTER on keyboard and get to new activity.
I do it this way but it doesn't work

```
   val password: EditText = findViewById(R.id.password)
   password.setOnKeyListener{ _, keyCode, keyEvent ->
        if (keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (password.equals("112")) {
                Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java).also { startActivity(it) }
            }
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        }
        false
    }
```

Comment: First You are comparing the `EditText` to `"112"`. You should make Your condition like this:
`if (password.text.toString() =="112")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing editText instance with 112 which is causing the trouble. You need to compare editText text with the actual text i.e 112

```
val password: EditText = findViewById(R.id.password)
   password.setOnKeyListener{ _, keyCode, keyEvent ->
        if (keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (password.getText().toString().equals("112")) { // use getText() to get the text of password editText here
                Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java).also { startActivity(it) }
            }
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        }
        false
    }
```